# Add values from an array to another array

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

I have the following two arrays in pure JavaScript:

```js
var smiley_descriptions = [
  'smiley', 'sad', 'wink', 'laugh', 'cheeky', 'blush', 'surprise',
  'indecision', 'angry', 'angel', 'cool', 'devil', 'crying', 'kiss'
];
var smiley_textual_descriptions = [
  ':)', ':(', ';)', ':D', ':P', ':*)', ':-o', ':|',  '>:(', 'o:)',  
  '8-)', '>:-)',  ';(', ':-*'
];
```

I want to add the values from one array to obtain the following result, but I don't understand how to do it:

```js
var my_new_array = {smiley: ':)', sad: ':(', wink: ';)', laugh: ':D', cheeky: ':P', blush: ':*)', surprise: ':-o', indecision: ':|', angry: '>:(', angel: 'o:)', cool: '8-)', devil: '>:-)', crying: ';(', kiss: ':-*'};
```

Do you have any idea how to do it ?

Comment: The expected output is invalid. Do you want an object as output?

Comment: I think what you want is `output = {smiley: ':)', sad: ':(', wink: ';)', laugh: ':D', cheeky: ':P', blush: ':*)', surprise: ':-o', indecision: ':|', angry: '>:(', angel: 'o:)', cool: '8-)', devil: '>:-)', crying: ';(', kiss: ':-*'}`

Comment: That is not a valid format, in JavaScript; what you you can have is a multi dimensional array like `[['smiley', ':)'], ['sad', ':('], ['wink', ';)']]` or an object like `{ smiley: ':)', sad: ':(', wink: ';)' }`.

Comment: Sorry, i had made a mistake but i fixed the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of getting an array of an object that has one element, it will be great to get an object instead.

```js
var smiley_descriptions = [
    'smiley', 'sad', 'wink', 'laugh', 'cheeky', 'blush', 'surprise',
    'indecision', 'angry', 'angel', 'cool', 'devil', 'crying', 'kiss'
];
var smiley_textual_descriptions = [
    ':)', ':(', ';)', ':D', ':P', ':*)', ':-o', ':|',  '>:(', 'o:)',  '8-)',  '>:-)',  ';(', ':-*'
];

const result = {};
smiley_descriptions.forEach((item, index) => {
   result[item] = smiley_textual_descriptions[index];
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your intended result is syntactically wrong.

If you want an array of objects (as key from one and the value from other) then you can try using `map()` like the following way:

```js
var smiley_descriptions = [
'smiley', 'sad', 'wink', 'laugh', 'cheeky', 'blush', 'surprise',
'indecision', 'angry', 'angel', 'cool', 'devil', 'crying', 'kiss'
];
 var smiley_textual_descriptions = [
':)', ':(', ';)', ':D', ':P', ':*)', ':-o', ':|',  '>:(', 'o:)',  '8-)',  '>:-)',  ';(', ':-*'
];

var my_new_array = smiley_descriptions.map((k,i) => ({[k]: smiley_textual_descriptions[i]}));

console.log(my_new_array);
```

**Update:** according to the required corrected result. You can use `Object.assign()`, spread syntax and `map()`:

```js
var smiley_descriptions = [
'smiley', 'sad', 'wink', 'laugh', 'cheeky', 'blush', 'surprise',
'indecision', 'angry', 'angel', 'cool', 'devil', 'crying', 'kiss'
];
 var smiley_textual_descriptions = [
':)', ':(', ';)', ':D', ':P', ':*)', ':-o', ':|',  '>:(', 'o:)',  '8-)',  '>:-)',  ';(', ':-*'
];

var my_new_array = Object.assign(...smiley_descriptions.map((k, i) => ({[k]: smiley_textual_descriptions[i]})));

console.log(my_new_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to implement this.

```js
var smiley_descriptions = [
  'smiley',
  'sad',
  'wink',
  'laugh',
  'cheeky',
  'blush',
  'surprise',
  'indecision',
  'angry',
  'angel',
  'cool',
  'devil',
  'crying',
  'kiss'
];

var smiley_textual_descriptions = [
  ':)',
  ':(',
  ';)',
  ':D',
  ':P',
  ':*)',
  ':-o',
  ':|',
  '>:(',
  'o:)',
  '8-)',
  '>:-)',
  ';(',
  ':-*'
];

const result = smiley_descriptions.reduce(
  (val, cur, index) => ({
    ...val,
    [cur]: smiley_textual_descriptions[index]
  }),
  {}
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with index.

```js
var smiley_descriptions = [
  'smiley', 'sad', 'wink', 'laugh', 'cheeky', 'blush', 'surprise',
  'indecision', 'angry', 'angel', 'cool', 'devil', 'crying', 'kiss'
];
var smiley_textual_descriptions = [
  ':)', ':(', ';)', ':D', ':P', ':*)', ':-o', ':|', '>:(', 'o:)', '8-)', '>:-)', ';(', ':-*'
];

const my_new_array = smiley_descriptions.reduce((acc, cur, index) => {
  acc[cur] = smiley_textual_descriptions[index];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(my_new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to map your `smiley_descriptions` array to an array of `[[key, value], ...]` pair entries, where each `value` is an associated value from your other array at the same index. You can then use this key-value pair entry array to build an object using Object.fromEntries:

```js
const smiley_descriptions = ['smiley', 'sad', 'wink', 'laugh', 'cheeky', 'blush', 'surprise', 'indecision', 'angry', 'angel', 'cool', 'devil', 'crying', 'kiss' ];
const smiley_textual_descriptions = [ ':)', ':(', ';)', ':D', ':P', ':*)', ':-o', ':|',  '>:(', 'o:)',  '8-)',  '>:-)',  ';(', ':-*' ];

const res = Object.fromEntries(smiley_descriptions.map(
  (desc, i) => [desc, smiley_textual_descriptions[i]])
);
console.log(res);
```